# Python3: Assign name from other list to a file that is named something else

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, for-loop

When looping through the html data of an email I grab the hyperlink to each text and when it saves, it does so as an embed file with the links name in a directory as `httpgooglecom2021` . However I want to overwrite the file with the appropriate names that come from a separate list. i.e. `httpgooglecom2021 to poster.pdf`

Below grabs the html data of the email and removes all whitespaces.

```
    links = [elem.strip().split('\r\n')for elem in message.body['html']]
```

Here the code loops through the html data and with regex finds the address bars of which an embedded link is from and downloads it to the download folder, as well as the plain text to find their actual names.
The 3rd for loop within the code seems to be my problem, where it will overwrite each file with the same name thus only creating 1 file.

```
    for index, b in enumerate(links):
        try:
            hyperlinks = re.findall("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", str(b))
            filenames= re.findall("\w+\.pdf|\w+.jpg|\w+.png|\w+.jpeg",str(b))
            pdf_fn = temp

            for url in hyperlinks:
                index = ''.join(e for e in url if e.isalnum())
                for name in filenames:
                    index2 = ''.join(map(str,name))
                download_link = f"{path}/{name}"
                r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    with open(download_link, 'wb') as fp:
                        for data in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024* 8):
                            fp.write(data)
                            fp.flush()
                            os.fsync(fp.fileno())
                else:
                    print("CANNOT DOWNLOAD FILE!! status code: {}\n{}".format(r.status_code,r.text))
        except:
            pass
            print(traceback.print_exc())
```

Comment: From your explanation, I can't understand either what you are trying to accomplish nor what is your problem.  What does the statement "The files can be .pngs or .jpgs etc. so I can not just append it to the end." mean? Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I believe I edited the problem with the relevant text necessary now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out it was a simple change from a for loop to a while loop so

```
while (i < len(hyperlinks)):
                download_link = f"{path}/{filenames[i]}"
                r = requests.get(hyperlinks[i], allow_redirects=True)
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    with open(download_link, 'wb') as fp:
                        for data in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024* 8):
                            fp.write(data)
                            fp.flush()
                            os.fsync(fp.fileno())
                else:
                    print("CANNOT DOWNLOAD FILE!! status code: {}\n{}".format(r.status_code,r.text))
                i += 1
```